# php file path of server

Tags: php

I am trying to get this script to work. it opens up a directry and lists the files in the directory.
I have copied this code from somewhere else and the problem is that this php file is hosted on an apache server not my localhost. what is the correct $dir_name = "c:/"; to use?

The file is in this directory /domains/domainxxxx.com.au/public_html/lsitfiles.php so would I use domainxxxx.com.au/public_html/lsitfiles.php ?

```
<?php

$dir_name = "c:/";

$dir = opendir($dir_name);

$file_list = "<ul>";

while ($file_name = readdir($dir)) {
    if(($file_name != ".") && (file_name != "..")) {
    $file_list .= "<li>$file_name"; 
                               }
}

$file_list.= "<ul>";

closedir($dir);

?>

<HTML>
<BODY>

<p>Files in: <? echo "$dir_name"; ?></p>
<? echo "$file_list"; ?>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends which folder you want to scan.

Obviously, you cannot scan any folder on client's computer. I guess you know that.

If you want to scan folder where the script resides it's best to use:

```
$dir_name = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$dir_name` is the folder you want to scan. Where you upload your script, you can specify the folders there from using absolute or relative paths upward and backward eg `../foldername` or `myfolder/myfolder2`.

Comment: The file is in this directory
/domains/domainxxxx.com.au/public_html/lsitfiles.php 
so would i use domainxxxx.com.au/public_html/lsitfiles.php ?

Comment: Maybe first tell us WHICH folder you want to scan? The folder where script resides? Home folder on server?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on OS. In Linux it would be '/'.
P.S. If server is configured properly, you should not be able to read '/' (or 'c:/').