# How to define folder path php?

Tags: php, filepath

I am trying to define a path in php like

```
 getcwd().'\json_files\'.$file_info['filename'];
```

but its not working, here `$file_info['filename'];` is file name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php file path of server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643774/php-file-path-of-server)

Comment: Are you using forward or backward slashes? Does that matter to your server? Look at [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php).

Comment: Just to mention my file is not in the same directory so dirname(__FILE__); is not working

Comment: @Greg Sorry, i just updated my question.

Comment: DIRECTORY separator resolved the issue but then i have to use it multiple times with concatenation if my file path is lengthy.

Comment: Call `dirname(__FILE__);` and use it as the basis for a relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using backslashes in a file path only works on Windows computers. Chances are that you are developing in Windows and the server the code is running on is Unix-like (using forward slashes).

The [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant is used to define whether the current system uses forward or backward slashes for this, but there is a really nice answer:

**Just use forward slashes**

If you are on Linux, forward slashes work. If you are on Mac, forward slashes work. Most importantly, if you are on Windows, forward slashes work.

You only need to know what the system's directory separator character is when you are comparing paths provided by the operating system.